# How to assign emission material to Line Art modifier?

Tags: materials, modifiers, shaders, grease-pencil, lineart

I'm using the Line Art modifier on a grease pencil stroke assigned to a mesh. However the materials that are available to paint the stroke with are only diffuse shaders.

Is there a way to make the resulting outline have an emission value ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you :

In the Object Properties for your stroke, you can uncheck "use lights" so the materials don't case lights.  That's not emission though.